# How to get all document with max date?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

i'm trying to get, from my MongoDB, all documents with the higher date.
My db is look like :

```
_id:"1"
date:"21-12-20"
report:"some stuff"

_id:"2"
date:"11-11-11"
report:"qualcosa"

_id:5fe08735b5a28812866cbc8a
date:"21-12-20"
report:Object

_id:5fe0b35e2f465c2a2bbfc0fd
date:"20-12-20"
report:"ciao"
```

and i would like to have a result like :

```
_id:"1"
date:"21-12-20"
report:"some stuff"

_id:5fe08735b5a28812866cbc8a
date:"21-12-20"
report:Object
```

I tried to run this script :

```
db.collection.find({}).sort([("date", -1)]).limit(1)
```

but it gives me only one document.

How can I get all the documents with the greatest date automatically?

Comment: Why on earth do you store date values as **strings** - and even with 2-year digit? Did you never hear about the [Y2K-Bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem)? Does `21-12-20` mean `2021-12-20` or `2020-12-21`? (or `1921-12-20` or even `0021-12-20`)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `limit(1)` and it's gonna work

Comment: Your solution is wrong , because it gives all the documents not only those with the greatest date.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `.limit(1)` it's only ever going to give you one document.

Either use the answer as a query to another `.find()`, or you can write an aggregate query. If you data set is a modest size, I prefer the former for clarity.

```
max_date = list(db.collection.find({}).sort([("date", -1)])).limit(1)
if len(max_date) > 0:
    db.collection.find({'date': max_date[0]['date']})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggest, I've already tried your solution and it works but i'm looking for a solution with only one query to the database and not two. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: I never understand why people want to do stuff in "one query". You have a great language in python to do this stuff easily. If you're not capable of writing your own aggregate queries then you won't be capable to support them later.

Comment: With this code you will query the MongoDB two times. Doing it in "one query" is faster because you access the DB only once.

Comment: My point being it's not faster if you don't know how to do it.

Comment: Another reason to use only one query **could** be: The data may change between the first and second find. Of course, most likely it is not relevant here, however there might be reasons which require a single query.

Answer (score 0):

Use an aggregation pipeline like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $group: { _id: null, data: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } },
   {
      $set: {
         data: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$data",
               cond: { $eq: [{ $max: "$data.date" }, "$$this.date"] }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $unwind: "$data" },
   { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$data" } }
])
```